# jquery regex selector

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-selectors

I want to select some html elements with name starting with btn (btn1, btn2..)

what is the most efficiant way to do that

I try http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/ but dont manage to make it work

```
$(':regex(class,btn[0-9]').hover( function(){

// not selecting any "btn" class

}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you want to select all elements that have a `class` attribute that starts with the word `btn`:

```
$( '[class^=btn]' )
```

If you want to use the `name` attribute instead, just swap out the attribute:

```
$( '[name^=btn]' )
```

Using the attribute value starts-with selector: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: This is a much better answer.  Regex is expensive. Edited to answer the question more directly.

Answer (score 5):

What you are doing is selecting all elements with the class of btnX where X could be 0-9.

To do this with the name attribute starting with "btn" you need to use:

```
$(':regex(name,^btn)').hover(function() { ... }, function() { ... });
```

-- **EDIT to include *[working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CodeMaverick/ezk7Q/)*** --

Also, don't forget to put this on your page:

```
jQuery.expr[':'].regex = function(elem, index, match) {
    var matchParams = match[3].split(','),
        validLabels = /^(data|css):/,
        attr = {
            method: matchParams[0].match(validLabels) ?
                        matchParams[0].split(':')[0] : 'attr',
            property: matchParams.shift().replace(validLabels,'')
        },
        regexFlags = 'ig',
        regex = new RegExp(matchParams.join('').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''), regexFlags);
    return regex.test(jQuery(elem)[attr.method](attr.property));
}
```

Comment: thanks , I dont know what I was missing maybe the ^ before btn

Comment: @N-AccessDev - You were using `$(':regex(class,btn[0-9])')` which is looking for all HTML elements that have a **class** with the name of **btn0** through **btn9**.  Mine uses `$(':regex(name,^btn)')` which is looking for all HTML elements that have a **name** starting with **btn**.

Comment: @N-AccessDev - That said, I do agree with Eli that the :regex way of going about things is going to be a lot slower than just using the right selector.  However, he is wrong in his answer, as you were looking for all HTML elements that start with the name of "btn".  Which means that you should use `$('[name^="btn"]')`.  That would be the most efficient way of selecting those particular elements.

Comment: This regex version really helps me out here as I need to select objects that have a specific format with variables in it. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt regex is the most efficient way to do it, but did you add the regex selector to your code?  `:regex` is not a built-in selector so you need to include the snippet at the top of your article in your script.